# Non-greedy lookahead regex

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, match

I have a file I need to extract some data from, in Python. Its structure is as follows:

```
.I 1
.T
some multiline text
.A
some multiline text
.B
some multiline text
.W
some multiline text
.I 2
.T
some multiline text
.A
some multiline text
.B
some multiline text
.W
some multiline text
```

As you see, there some repeating repeating patterns. I need to extract them one by one. This is my eegex:

```
\.I\s(\d*)\n       # .I section
\.T\n([\d\D]*?)    # .T section
\.A\n([\d\D]*?)    # .A section
\.B\n([\d\D]*?)    # .B section
\.W\n([\d\D]*)     # .W section
(?=\.I\s+\d+)     # look ahead section, which behaves greedy
```

Everything is OK, but the last section (lookahead) which is greedy. I need a non-greedy lookahead regex, but I couldn't find it.

We can apply a non-greedy behavior using `*?` `+?` `{m,n}?` but I couldn't find such a syntax for `(?=...)`

When I search for a match with this regex, it only finds one match while there are two. This is because of the greedy nature of the lookahead operator. How can I have a non-greedy lookahead?

Comment: when i paste your regex in regex101.com, it tells me there is an error with the last question mark. do you see that too?

Comment: also, don't you want `\.W\n([\d\D]*?)` ?

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, but this `(?=\.I\s+\d+|$)‍‍‍‍‍‍` only helps to find the last pattern, but my problem is greedy nature of look ahead.

Comment: Then remove the lookahead. They cannot be greedy or lazy. They restrict the match. If your lookahead only contains optional sub patterns it is of no use.

Comment: @Julien, A misplaced question mark at the end of regex was source of error. Now it is corrected.

Comment: @Julien, this regex  `\.W\n([\d\D]*?)` coudn't match the body of `.W` section

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think you're right

Comment: @Wiktor, if i remove look ahead, then there is no way to match body of `.W` section

Comment: @Fartab ... it should match, your .W section is no different than the others, it should work the same

Comment: @Fartab also, i tested the reggae below (see my answer) in regex101 and seems to be matching everything fine.

Comment: @Julien, You are right. Thanks. That solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.

Comment: Oh, i forgot, @WiktorStribiżew thank you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fail to see why the greediness of the look ahead is important, I would expect the following to work:

```
\.I\s(\d*)\n
\.T\n([\d\D]*?)
\.A\n([\d\D]*?)
\.B\n([\d\D]*?)
\.W\n([\d\D]*?)
(?=\.I\s+\d+|$)
```

Now that I think about it, I think that Wiktor Stribiżew is right. A look ahead cannot be greedy or lazy: either there is a match or there is not and what it matches does not matter.

Comment: My mistake was missing question mark after .W section and also a $ needed for the last match. Thanks @Julien

Comment: What it matches does matter though!  How do you tell it to match the first match instead of the last?

Comment: @MattArnold A lookahead consumes no characters; it just asserts that at the current scan position you can match some regex but it any event it doesn't actually advance the scan position matching/consuming characters. For example, if I wanted to ensure that a string `s` contains at least one lower-case ascii character I could use either `m = re.match(r'(?=.*[a-z])', s)` or `m = re.match('(?=.*?[a-z])', s)` and each regex will return the same value of `m` for a given input and if `m` is not None, `m.group(0)` nevertheless will be the empty string.

Comment: @Booboo But which instance of the lower-case character being matched does matter when using REGEX for Find and Replace.